# When .append(), or .html() the css and js is not taking effect

Tags: jquery

I have Multi Select which I would like to append it to a div, when I append, or html it to div the CSS or js not taking effect so it show as basic multi select. 
but when I copy ('#table').text("...") and past it in the div it work fine.
I attached image so you can take look it.

```
    var table = "<select id=\"s11\" class=\"s11\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option>All</option><option selected=\"selected\">Low</option><option selected=\"selected\">Medium</option><option selected=\"selected\">High</option></select>";
  $('.table').html(table);
```

This image when I copy the Code directly in div tag :
[image]

This image is when I append or html to the div class: [image]

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post samples, not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry I will go head and do It

Comment: I have hard time to add all dropdownchecklist.js in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a jQuery plugin to make a checkable selection .

For example, let says your function is dropdownchecklist():

```
$('select').dropdownchecklist();  // may not be exactly this method
```

Then you have to use the same function after adding select element:

```
var table = "<select id=\"s11\" class=\"s11\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option>All</option><option selected=\"selected\">Low</option><option selected=\"selected\">Medium</option><option selected=\"selected\">High</option></select>";
  $('.table').html(table);
  $('.table #s11').dropdownchecklist();
```